# Tuples/ Records in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tuples, immutability, record, ecmascript-next

I was referring to this link: [Future Javascript: Records and Tuples](https://dev.to/smpnjn/future-javascript-records-and-tuples-14fk) and I was wondering, what is the reasoning behind these?

We can still use `Object.freeze` with both arrays and objects to achieve this. Only reasoning I can think of is *compare by value*. So this will allow us to have complex object like structure(*records*) in `Set` as keys and we can fetch them without much hassle. But does this look big enough reason to add new datatype in a language?

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) protects writing access just at an object's first (entry/property) level. Any structure nested deeper than 1 is writable. Thus a *frozen* object never is *deeply frozen*.

In order to achieve the latter one has to write ones' own recursive `deepFreeze` function.

In contrast the future primitive `Record` and `Tuple` values are truly/entirely immutable.

```js
const wellTempered = {
  foo: {
    bar: 'baz',
    biz: {
      buzz: 'booz',
    },
  },
  safe: 'protected',
};
const frozen = Object.freeze(wellTempered);

console.log(
  '(wellTempered === frozen) ?..',
  (wellTempered === frozen),
);

// - level 1 is frozen, thus not writable.
// - writing attempts will fail silently
//   in non strict mode.

frozen.safe = 'vulnerable';

// - `freeze` doesn't freeze deeply.
//
// - nested levels deeper than 1
//   are still writable.

frozen.foo.bar = "fooled";
frozen.foo.biz.buzz = "doomed";

console.log({
  wellTempered,
  frozen,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Any nested structure will be mutable. If you add an array inside a record, which you can, you will be able to add/ remove items from it. Their idea is for us to only use tuples and record but it does not make them immutable at further levels

Comment: I have to see a line of code which demonstrates how one would _"...add an array inside a record..."_.